# Using expect on stderr (sshuttle as an example)

Tags: bash, expect

There is this program called `sshuttle` that can connects to a server and create a tunnel.

I wish to create a bash function that sequentially:

- 1. opens a tunnel to a remote server (`sshuttle -r myhost 0/0`),
- 2. performs 1 arbitrary commandline,
- 3. `kill -s TERM <pidOfTheAboveTunnel>`.

A basic idea (that works but the 5 seconds delay is a problem) is like `sshuttle -r myhost 0/0 & ; sleep 5 ; mycommand ; kill -s TERM $(pgrep sshuttle)`

Could `expect` be used to expect the string "c : Connected to server." that is received from stderr here? My attempts as a newbie were met with nothing but failure, and the man page is quite impressive.

Comment: I'm not clear about one thing here - is `mycommand` to be executed on the remote server or on the local machine?

Comment: yes `mycommand` is to be run locally, we just want to run local commands but with an altered network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `expect` to control another program, it connects to that program through a pseudo-terminal (pty), so expect sees the same output from the program as you would on a terminal, in particular there is no distinction between stdout and stderr.  Assuming that your `mycommand` is to be executed on the local machine, you could use something like this as an expect (not bash) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn sshuttle -r myhost 0/0
expect "Connected to server."
exec mycommand
exec kill [exp_pid]
close
```

The `exec kill` may not be needed if sshuttle exits when its stdin is closed, which will happen on the next line.

Comment: Perfect! I knew this thing was amazing. So are you :) Thanks